# scikit-learn is not working and gives an error "module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xe"

Tags: python, machine-learning

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xe
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Means exactly what it says; your scikit-learn was built for a newer version of numpy than the one you have installed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It actually means something different, having one version of numpy installed but a different version of the native numpy library.

Comment: Can you try this: `pip3 install -U numpy` this fixed my problem